# Replace an existing element

Tags: javascript, element

```
if (yardss > 0.1 && yardss < 0.3) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/wrench1.jpg";
    img.align = "center";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
} else if (yardss > 0.3) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/wrench.jpg";
    img.width = 500;
    img.height = 300;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

This script is activated by the user clicking on a button, and it prompts the user to enter a certain number of yards. If the yards are above a certain number, it displays a certain sized wrench. If it is below a certain number, it displays a different sized wrench.
My problem is that because the script can be run over and over again by clicking on the button, every time that the script is run, a new image of a wrench is produced below the previous image, creating a really long web page with a lot of images.

How do I make the newly created image replace the image created from the previous running of the script, instead of having the page fill with images from the script being run multiple times?

Comment: Put an ID on the image and remove it.

Comment: Use JQuery to update the image.  Do not append a new one each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create the `img` element again and again. Just create once and set some `id` on it. Then just change the `src` and `width`, `height` etc..

In HTML:

```
<img id= "wrench_img"/>                         // Setting id as wrench_img
```

In JavaScript:

```
function changer(yardss) {
    var img1 = document.getElementById("wrench_img"); // Get the img 
    if (yardss > 0.1 && yardss < 0.3) {
        img1.src = "images/wrench1.jpg";              // Change the src
        img1.align = "center";
    } else if (yardss > 0.3) {
        img1.src = "images/wrench.jpg";               // Change the src
        img1.width = 500;                             // Change width
        img1.height = 300;
    }
}
```

In your code, you were appending new image elements to the `document.body`. That is why you were getting multiple image elements. But if you look at this code, we don't create the image elements multiple times. We just change the one created.

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CsUFX/)

Comment: This is the one that worked, however, using a variable name like img1 absolutely would not work. Everything had to be named img. Even copying from the online demo to use img1 would not work. Thank you very much though.

Comment: @zavtra Actually, I forgot to separate the HTML and JavaScript part. The updated one should be fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild) instead of `appendChild`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the `.src` property on the current image.  There is no need to create a whole new image:

```
// get the current image object
// assumes you set id="wrenchImg" on it
var img = document.getElementById("wrenchImg");
if (yardss > 0.1 && yardss < 0.3) {
    img.src = "images/wrench1.jpg";
    img.height = ...   // set this to whatever you need it to be for this image
    img.width = ...    // set this to whatever you need it to be for this image
    img.align = "center";
} else if (yardss > 0.3) {
    img.src = "images/wrench.jpg";
    img.height = 300;
    img.width = 500;
    img.align = "left";
}
```

If you have any other properties of the image that must also be changed (height or width or alignment, for example), then you can add those to each branch of the `if/else`, but doing it this way, you have to fully initialize the image object because it may have been set a different way based on the previous image.